# Animate RecyclerView when scrolling

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview

Is there any way to animate the elements of a RecyclerView when I scroll it?

I took a look at `DefaultItemAnimator` and `RecyclerView.ItemAnimator`, but that animations seems to be only called if the dataset has changed, please correct me if I am wrong.

I'm a little confused about `RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.animateMove()` when is it called? I put some breakpoints into that class but none of them stops my app.

However back to my question how can I animate the RecyclerView? I want that some elements have another opacity, depended on some custom rules.

---

I did some more reaseach it seems that animation move is exactly that what I'm looking for. That methods are called from `dispatchLayout()`. Here is the javadoc of that method:

> Wrapper around layoutChildren() that handles animating changes caused by layout.
>    Animations work on the assumption that there are five different kinds of items
>    in play:
>    PERSISTENT: items are visible before and after layout
>    REMOVED: items were visible before layout and were removed by the app
>    ADDED: items did not exist before layout and were added by the app
>    DISAPPEARING: items exist in the data set before/after, but changed from
>    visible to non-visible in the process of layout (they were moved off
>    screen as a side-effect of other changes)
>    APPEARING: items exist in the data set before/after, but changed from
>    non-visible to visible in the process of layout (they were moved on
>    screen as a side-effect of other changes)
>    The overall approach figures out what items exist before/after layout and
>    infers one of the five above states for each of the items. Then the animations
>    are set up accordingly:
>    PERSISTENT views are moved ({@link ItemAnimator#animateMove(ViewHolder, int, int, int, int)})
>    REMOVED views are removed ({@link ItemAnimator#animateRemove(ViewHolder)})
>    ADDED views are added ({@link ItemAnimator#animateAdd(ViewHolder)})
>    DISAPPEARING views are moved off screen
>    APPEARING views are moved on screen

So far I'm looking for PERSISTENT, DISAPPEARING and APPEARING, but that methods are never called because of this line here:

```
boolean animateChangesSimple = mItemAnimator != null && mItemsAddedOrRemoved
            && !mItemsChanged;
```

`mItemsAddedOrRemoved` is simply always false so none of that callback are ever reached. Any idea how to set set flag correctly?

Comment: you can use objectanimtor introduced in api11 for animating any object

Comment: Well fine but how do I know when I need to start the animation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ended in using an `OnScrollListener` and animating it in a custom `animate()` method. In my case that code takes just 2ms so that is no problem for the 60fps.

```
recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(int newState) {
        if(newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            // special handler to avoid displaying half elements
            scrollToNext();
        }
        animate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(int dx, int dy) {
        animate();
    }
});
```

Comment: can you add a bit more code - like scrollToNext for example?

Comment: That is out of the scope of my question. You should ask a independ question about that. Keep in mind to show your current progress while implementing that :)

Comment: @rekire can you please help me with my question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858059/recyclerview-settle-item-with-decelerate-interpolator-once-scroll-finishes

Answer (score 6):

I did it this way. Might help someone. I don't know whether it's the best way to do it but works fine for me.

**UPDATE:** 
To fix fast scrolling behaviour, override `onViewDetachedFromWindow` method of the adapter and call `clearAnimation` on the animated view (in this case, `holder.itemView.clearAnimation()` ).

`up_from_bottom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shareInterpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="400" />
</set>
```

`down_from_top.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shareInterpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="400" />
</set>
```

And finally put this code in `onBindViewHolder` of `recyclerView`. Create a field called lastPosition and initialize it to -1.

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
            (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom
                    : R.anim.down_from_top);
    holder.itemView.startAnimation(animation);
    lastPosition = position;
```

Comment: the animation show up again when notifiydatasetchange. Any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The good solution is to animate holder in adapter in `onBindViewHolder` method. 
Snippet taken from Material Test project Slidenerd:

```
@Override 
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderBoxOffice holder, int position) {
    Movie currentMovie = mListMovies.get(position);
    //one or more fields of the Movie object may be null since they are fetched from the web 
    holder.movieTitle.setText(currentMovie.getTitle());


    //retrieved date may be null 
    Date movieReleaseDate = currentMovie.getReleaseDateTheater();
    if (movieReleaseDate != null) {
        String formattedDate = mFormatter.format(movieReleaseDate);
        holder.movieReleaseDate.setText(formattedDate);
    } else { 
        holder.movieReleaseDate.setText(Constants.NA);
    } 


    int audienceScore = currentMovie.getAudienceScore();
    if (audienceScore == -1) {
        holder.movieAudienceScore.setRating(0.0F);
        holder.movieAudienceScore.setAlpha(0.5F);
    } else { 
        holder.movieAudienceScore.setRating(audienceScore / 20.0F);
        holder.movieAudienceScore.setAlpha(1.0F);
    } 


    if (position > mPreviousPosition) {
        AnimationUtils.animateSunblind(holder, true);         
    } else { 
        AnimationUtils.animateSunblind(holder, false);

    } 
    mPreviousPosition = position;
```

here is a [link](https://github.com/slidenerd/materialtest/blob/master/app/src/main/java/materialtest/vivz/slidenerd/adapters/AdapterMovies.java)

Comment: This solution for a certain library not for all.