# Expand CardView inside RecyclerView as New Activity like Inbox by Google Android

Tags: android, listview, material-design, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm Using Recycler View as my listview and CardView as list item. I want to expand the Cardview when I click on any item of the list like it expands in inbox app by Google/Gmail. Please guide!

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/implementing-material-design-in-your.html check Activity + Fragment Transitions

Comment: I Already check this But unable to implement it in my code. Please explain!

Comment: @random activity + fragment transitions only work with android 5 but inbox works with less than that. Point to be noted !!

Comment: Yes, I note this, and That's why following inbox.

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed  you might be interested in watching this devbytes https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA and this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344357/android-5-activity-transition-on-lower-api

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed : Any best sample code?

Answer (score 3):

*Trick:* You can change one of your item's `height` (inside your `CardView`) in your `adapter`. 
For example i have `TextView` in my `CardView`, when `CardView` item is clicked, i change height of `TextView` to `300`:

```
public class courseListAdapter extends ListAdapter<courseListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
....
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements
                View.OnClickListener,View.OnLongClickListener{
    TextView courseCRN;      
    ....
    public ViewHolder(View itemView, ClickListener listener)  {
        super(itemView);
        courseCRN = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.course_crn);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {   

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 300, 1f);
                    courseCRN.setLayoutParams(lp);


     }
}
```

**Initial:**

[image]

**Later:**

[image]

Comment: But does this replace the toolbar with the new toolbar like view with sleak transitions?

Comment: @neaGaze No, this trick just changes `CardView` `height` when it is clicked.

Comment: i think you wanted something else :D

Comment: @neaGaze is right, it will just change the cardview height. The same thing can also be achieved using setting some item's visibility.

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed i think you can listen to recyclerview scroll state and change height again. Of yourse you can add transition to change height slowly. Check for scrollListener:http://stackoverflow.com/a/25481140/3736955

Comment: there is not scroll inside cardview, it is just list item. Recyclerview has scrolling.