# Recycler view animation on new item (Chat app) Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Hello guys am trying to add animation to my chat application wherein when the user sends a message it shows animation like sliding up and show animation when other user sends message but I am not able to find any suitable solutions https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators I have seen this library but I don't know how to and where to implement these so I hope anyone can help me

This is my Adapter class

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private final Context mContext;
private final List<Chat> mChat;
private final String imageUrl;


FirebaseUser firebaseUser;



public static final int MSG_TYPE_LEFT = 0;
public static final int MSG_TYPE_RIGHT = 1;

public static final int REPLY_TYPE_LEFT = 2;
public static final int REPLY_TYPE_RIGHT = 3;

private final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

private int lastAnimatedPosition = -1;


public MessageAdapter(Context mContext, List<Chat> mChat, String imageUrl,SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mChat = mChat;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.sharedPreferences = sharedPreferences;

}







@NonNull
@Override
public MessageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == MSG_TYPE_RIGHT) {

        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.chat_item_right, parent, false);
        return new MessageAdapter.ViewHolder(viewGroup);
    }
    if (viewType == MSG_TYPE_LEFT) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.chat_item_left, parent, false);
        return new MessageAdapter.ViewHolder(viewGroup);

    }

    if (viewType == REPLY_TYPE_RIGHT) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.chat_reply_right, parent, false);
        return new MessageAdapter.ViewHolder(viewGroup);
    } else {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.chat_reply_left, parent, false);
        return new MessageAdapter.ViewHolder(viewGroup);
    }



}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if(mChat.get(position).getSender().equals(firebaseUser.getUid()))
    {
        if(mChat.get(position).getReply().equals("true")) {
            return REPLY_TYPE_RIGHT;
        }else{
            return MSG_TYPE_RIGHT;
        }

    }
    else {
        if(mChat.get(position).getReply().equals("true")){
            return REPLY_TYPE_LEFT;
        }else{
            return MSG_TYPE_LEFT;
        }

    }



}

@Override
public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(final ViewHolder holder) {
    holder.clearAnimation();
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Chat chat = mChat.get(position);
    holder.username.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    holder.show_message.setText(chat.getMessage());
    holder.timestamp.setText(chat.getTimestamp());


    if(chat.getReply().equals("true")){

        if(chat.getReceiver().equals(chat.getReplyto())){
            holder.reply_txt_them.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.reply_txt_us.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.reply_username.setText(chat.getReplyname());
            holder.reply_txt_us.setText(chat.getReplytext());

        }else {
            holder.reply_txt_us.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.reply_txt_them.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.reply_username.setText(chat.getReplyname());
            holder.reply_txt_them.setText(chat.getReplytext());
        }


    }


    if(imageUrl.equals("default"))
    {
        holder.profile.setImageResource(R.drawable.user);
    }else {
        Glide.with(mContext).load(imageUrl).into(holder.profile);
    }

    if(position == mChat.size()-1) {

        String read = sharedPreferences.getString(TEXT1, "");

        if(read.equals("0")){
            holder.txt_seen.setText("Delivered");
        }
        else {
            if (chat.getIsseen().equals("true")) {
                holder.txt_seen.setText("Read");
            }else {
                holder.txt_seen.setText("Delivered");
            }

        }
    }else {
        holder.txt_seen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    if (position == mChat.size()-1) {

        
        lastAnimatedPosition = position;
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.animation_from_right);
        animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        ((ViewHolder) holder).container.setAnimation(animation);
        animation.start();
    }



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mChat.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView show_message;
    public ImageView profile;
    public TextView txt_seen;
    public TextView timestamp;

    public TextView username;

    public TextView reply_txt_them;
    public TextView reply_txt_us;
    public TextView reply_username;
    public LinearLayout linearLayout;
    protected View container;

    public ViewHolder(View view){
        super(view);

        container = view;

        show_message = itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_message);
        profile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        txt_seen = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_seen);
        timestamp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
        username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        linearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_reply);
        reply_username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.reply_username);

        reply_txt_them = itemView.findViewById(R.id.replytextthem);
        reply_txt_us = itemView.findViewById(R.id.replytextus);
    }

    public void clearAnimation() {
        container.clearAnimation();
    }


}
```

}

As you can see I have tried to add animation but the problem is I have even added read recipients like thing so when ever the user sees the message it again refreshes and again the animation plays.

Comment: try using this for the scroll when a new item is added`smoothScrollToPosition()`

Comment: as parameter parse the position of the last item in the list

Comment: you could also follow the thread in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379867/animate-recyclerview-when-scrolling to animate the recyclerview onScroll